# Вывести отсортированный массив задом наперед

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
struct tnode
{
    int field;           
    struct tnode* left;  
    struct tnode* right; 
};

void treeprint(tnode* tree)
{
    if (tree != NULL) { 
        treeprint(tree->left);  
        cout << tree->field << " "; 
        treeprint(tree->right); 
    }
}
struct tnode* addnode(int x, tnode* tree) {
    if (tree == NULL)     
    {
        tree = new tnode; 
        tree->field = x;   
        tree->left = NULL;
        tree->right = NULL;
    }
    else     
        if (x < tree->field)   
            tree->left = addnode(x, tree->left); 
        else  
            tree->right = addnode(x, tree->right); 
    return(tree);
}
struct tnode* addnode(int x, tnode* tree,int ar[]) {
    if (tree == NULL)     
    {
        tree = new tnode;
        tree->field = x;   
        tree->left = NULL;
        tree->right = NULL; 
    }
    else     
        if (x < tree->field)  
            tree->left = addnode(x, tree->left); 
        else  
            tree->right = addnode(x, tree->right); 
    return(tree);
}
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    struct tnode* root = 0;    
    system("chcp 1251");    
    system("cls");
    int a;        
    cout << "Skol'ko 4isel dolzhno bit' v massive: ";
    cin >> a;
    int arr[100];
    cout << "Ishodniy massiv: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand() % 10;
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
    start = chrono::system_clock::now();
    cout << "Otsortirovaniy massiv: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        root = addnode(arr[i],root);
    } 
    treeprint(root);
    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    chrono::duration<float> duration = end - start;
    cout << endl;
    cout << " Duration = " << duration.count() << endl;
cout << endl;
    cin.get();  cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Вот такой выходит код с сортировкой, задание вывести его задом наперед и снова отсортировать(тот что задом наперед). Вот не знаю как это сделать, помогите кто-нибудь, пожалуйста.

Comment: Чтобы вывести задом на перед нужно поставить вывод после последнего рекурсивного вызова в treeprint

Comment: Я не до конца понимаю как это сделать, если не трудно, будьте добры поделиться примером своего кода

Comment: treeprint(tree->left);  
   treeprint(tree->right);  cout << tree->field << " ";

Comment: Сам разобрался, что нужно было treeprint(tree->right); cout << tree->field << " "; treeprint(tree->left);

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите просто вывести - то есть std::reverse_copy - просто скопируйте реверсов в stdout.

```
std::reverse_copy(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), std::ostream_iterator<uint64_t>{std::cout, " "});
```

Ну а если Вам нужно именно развернуть контейнер - используйте std::reverse

```
std::reverse(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec));
```

Вот пример кода:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <functional>


std::vector<int64_t> GenVector(uint64_t size, uint64_t low_bound, uint64_t hight_bound) {
    std::vector<int64_t> vec(size);
    std::mt19937_64 generator(std::random_device{}());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> uid(low_bound, hight_bound);
    auto gen{ std::bind(uid, generator) };
    std::generate(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), gen);

    return std::move(vec);
}


int main()
{
    const uint64_t size{10}, low_bound{ 0 }, hight_bound{100};

    auto vec{GenVector(size, low_bound, hight_bound)};

    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n") = std::string("Array before sort :");
    std::copy(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), std::ostream_iterator<uint64_t>{std::cout, " "});
    std::sort(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), std::less<int64_t>());

    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n") = std::string("After sort output :");
    std::copy(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), std::ostream_iterator<uint64_t>{std::cout, " "});

    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n") = std::string("Revers output :");
    std::reverse_copy(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), std::ostream_iterator<uint64_t>{std::cout, " "});

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А можно это как-то реализовать в моём коде, просто в векторах еще не разобрался и не отказался бы от, чтобы вы мне помогли с моим кодом(если можно, то еще нужно отсортировать еще раз реверснутый массив)

Comment: @t1nzy Лучше разберитесь с векторами . Меньше кода - меньше ошибок

Comment: Хорошо, в любом случае спасибо, хоть на верный путь указали.